# I can't create proper std::vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have to create a list of objects, so to keep it as smooth as possible I wanted to use std::vector instead of regular array of objects. However I don't exactly know how to use them properly. Here is sample code from my class in which I try to add objects to vecor and in 2nd method to display them.

```
private:
vector <Student> stud;
public:
void Student::dodaj(){
stud.push_back(Student(getNaz(), getImie(), getLeg(), getRok()));
}

void Student::wypisz(){
cout << "Lista osob:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Nazwisko: " << stud[i].nazwisko << endl;
    cout << "Imie: " << stud[i].imie << endl;
    cout << "Numer indeksu.: " << stud[i].legitymacja << endl;
    cout << "Rok studiow: " << stud[i].rok << endl;
}
```

And my main:

```
Student st("Kowalski", "Jan", 123455, 2);
Student test1("Nowak", "Jan", 123, 2);
st.dodaj();
test1.dodaj();
test1.wypisz();
```

However the output result is only one object for wich I use wypisz(print/display) method, in this case test1, that is displayed instead of two of them - st and test1. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Or the SO-specific version, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where do you ever add two objects to the same vector?

Comment: What's that incomplete class declaration at the beginning? The `Student` class? So each `Student` object holds its own vector of `Student`s? (why?)

Comment: It appears that each of your `Student`s contains its own vector and just adds itself to that vector when you call `dodaj`.

Comment: `class Student{
private:
 string nazwisko, imie;
 int legitymacja, rok;
 vector <Student> stud;

public:
 Student();
 Student(string naz, string im, int leg, int r);
 void dodaj();
 void wypisz();
 string getImie() { return imie; }
 string getNaz() { return nazwisko; }
 int getLeg() { return legitymacja; }
 int getRok() { return rok; }
`

Comment: In header file I think I create a vector of objects when using vector <Student> stud; .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `stud` is a member of `Student`, which means that each `Student` object contains its own vector. When you call `dodaj` on a particular student, it just adds its own details to the vector it contains.

```
st.dodaj(); // Adds details of st to st's own vector
test1.dodaj(); // Adds details of test1 to test1's own vector

// Now we have one vector inside st containing a single element
// and one vector inside test1 containing a single element    

test1.wypisz(); // Prints elements from test1's vector
```

Instead, your vector should be outside of your `Student` class (or at least static). One option would be to do this:

```
Student st("Kowalski", "Jan", 123455, 2);
Student test1("Nowak", "Jan", 123, 2);

std::vector<Student> stud;
std.push_back(st);
std.push_back(test1);
```

You may want to have another class (maybe `School`?) which contains this vector.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that is is UB to have a standard library container of an incomplete type.

Comment: So if I create another class my Student class should derive from it? Or there is no need for inheritance in this case?

Comment: @user4165421 Inheritance would be incorrect. That would mean a `Student` *is-a* `School` - definitely not right. Instead, a `School` *has-a* vector of `Student`s (that's the relationship that a member represents).

Comment: @JosephMansfield, should I use friend relationship or some other kind? The only idea that comes up to my mind is that I call 
`friend vector <Student> stud` in both `Student` and `School` class.

Comment: @user4165421 That wouldn't make sense. Please see this example I've written for you: http://ideone.com/pwYL2W.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, thanks alot! Now I see where were I doing mistakes. In between mine and Your's answer I made some fixes to my code and the final version was pretty similair to the one You posted.(I followed friend's advices too). I had problems with compiling, however it turned out to be headers include problem.